# Book about a character who stores time and can re-live the stored time

Tags: story-identification, novel, time

I'm looking to find out the title of a book I read in my final year of junior school.

I'm not sure of the exact plot, as this would have been in 2000, but from what I can remember, the story focuses on a boy who can somehow store periods of time (possibly memories), to be re-lived later on in life.
If I'm not mistaken, the main character later dies whilst re-living one of the stored periods of time.

I could possibly be off with how I'm remembering it, but I'd love to be able to find and read the book, as it's one of the few that have ever stuck with me and had some kind of impact on me.

Thanks in advance if anybody is able to help at all.

Comment: There is a character in Speaker for the Dead by Orson Scott Card. Olhado is his nickname. He has robotic cameras replacing his eyes. He can record memories to play back or turn his eyes off.

Comment: " Only one eye was used for sight, but it took four separate visual scans and then separated the signals to feed true binocular vision to the brain. The other eye contained the power supply, the computer control, and the external interface. When he wanted to, he could record short sequences of vision in a limited photo memory, probably less than a tril ion bits. The duelists were using him as their judge; if they disputed a point, he could replay the scene in slow motion and tel them what had happened. "

Comment: A bit similar to [Replay by Ken Grimwood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_(Grimwood_novel)): The novel tells of a 43-year-old man who dies and wakes up back in 1963 in his 18-year-old body. He relives his life with all his memories of the previous 25 years intact.

Comment: Yes, _Replay_ was what I immediately thought of though it's about a man reliving his life, not living it just once but reliving memories from his youth. It was published in 1987 so you could have read it around 2000.